# How to assign proportional dimensions to Fragments in a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to get 3 distinct `Fragment`'s displaced vertically at a single `Activity`.

I'd like to:

- Assign a proportional (preferently in percentage) height to each Fragment.
- Fragments should take whole device width.
- Change it's displacement according to rotation.

This is what my **Activity layout** looks like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/messageFragment"
        android:name="apps.android.expressa.expressa.Fragments.MessageFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/message_fragment_layout" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/listsFragment"
        android:name="apps.android.expressa.expressa.Fragments.ListsFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        tools:layout="@layout/lists_fragment_layout" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/bottomBarFragment"
        android:name="apps.android.expressa.expressa.Fragments.BottomBarFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        tools:layout="@layout/bottom_bar_layout" />


</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that right now, only first and second fragment and displayed and for third only a top is seen. As a note, I'm really new to Android *now*.

Comment: use android:layout_weight in child elements(fragments)  and android:weightSum for (LinearLayout)

Comment: You have applied a `weight` already but keep in mind that while you'r assigning a `weight` or `vertical` layout then you need to apply `height` as a `0dp` and `width` as a `0dp` for `horizontal` layout.

Comment: @PiyushGupta yes, He is using android:layout_height="match_parent" ,

Comment: I'd appreciate an explanatory answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="6" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/messageFragment"
    android:name="apps.android.expressa.expressa.Fragments.MessageFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:layout="@layout/message_fragment_layout" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/listsFragment"
    android:name="apps.android.expressa.expressa.Fragments.ListsFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    tools:layout="@layout/lists_fragment_layout" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/bottomBarFragment"
    android:name="apps.android.expressa.expressa.Fragments.BottomBarFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    tools:layout="@layout/bottom_bar_layout" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: For `android:weightSum="6"` what goes for rows and colums? Can I use a `heightSum` or `widthSum`?

Comment: And could you please add what comes when it's about a `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: as we put `android:orientation="vertical"` for `LinearLayout`.  `android:weightSum="6"` will effect as `widthSum`. for `RelativeLayout` we can't use `android:layout_weight`, (That's a property of [LinearLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html), but not of [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html))

Comment: well, you have to use `LinearLayout` in your case